# Select Scope Identity from Sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am executing an `Insert` query. I want to return the identity element. I am also using this same stored procedure. Inside another stored procedure to return the identity element.

```
Alter Proc Proc1 
    @name varchar(10),
    @value int
As
Begin
    insert into Table1 
    values (@name, @value)

    return SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

C# code:

I have a method to call my database every time, so I use that

```
_database.StoredProcedure = "Proc1";
_database.parameter("name","michael");
_database.parameter("value",10);

int id = Convert.ToInt32(_database.ExecuteScalar());
```

Here, I get id=0 every time //BUG

SQL other stored procedure:

```
Alter Proc2
// Some other logic
Execute @id = Proc1 @name, @value  // THIS WORKS
```

Now, If I change Proc1's last line to `Select SCOPE_IDENTITY()` from `RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()` then C# code works but Proc2 returns 0.

What should I do such that it works in C# code and in Proc2 also.

I thought about an output parameter, but I don't know how would I call it with my this database method in C#.

Comment: never use return for anything except an error code or status code , in other words it is for meta data only. You should use an output variable anytime you are returning actual data from a database table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SqlCommand return value parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885818/sqlcommand-return-value-parameter)

Comment: @Steve If I do Select SCOPE_IDENTITY(), **then the Proc2 id from Proc2 returns 0.**

Answer (score 4):

If you want data out of a procedure the correct thing is to use output parameters. Do NOT use the return_value from your procedures. This value indicates a status of the execution, not data from the procedure.

Here is an example of what this might look like.

```
Alter Proc Proc1 
 @name varchar(10),
 @value int,
 @IdentityValue int OUTPUT

As
Begin
    insert into Table1 values (@name,@value)
    Select @IdentityValue = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
select * from table1
GO

Alter Proc2
(
    @name varchar(10)
    , @value int
    , @IdentityValue int OUTPUT
)
as
    //SOme other logic
    declare @IdentityValue int
    Execute Proc1 @name, @value, @IdentityValue OUTPUT

GO
```

Also, please notice that you have an insert in Proc1 but you don't specify the columns. This is very bad practice. If your table structure changes your procedure is broken. You should ALWAYS specify the columns in your insert.

Comment: What should I do in my C# Code then. If I pass it as a parameter as `_database.Paramater("IdentityValue ", id);
_database.ExecuteNonQuery(); `. then id value is 0.

Comment: You have to add the parameter direction.

Answer (score 0):

Change your procedure body to like below, to change the `RETURN` statement to `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

```
Alter Proc Proc1 
 @name varchar(10),
 @value int
As
Begin
insert into Table1 values (@name,@value);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

In that case, make it a output parameter and set that output parameter to `scope_identity`

```
Alter Proc Proc1 
 @name varchar(10),
 @value int,
 @ID INT OUTPUT
As
Begin
insert into Table1 values (@name,@value);
SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

You can call the procedure

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "ID");
cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
int id = (int)cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value;
```

Comment: If I do Select SCOPE_IDENTITY(), then the Proc2 id from Proc2 returns 0.

Comment: In that case, make it a output parameter and set that output paameter to scope_identity